# Factorization of primes in an algebraic number field to which Dedekind-Kummer does not apply

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I am mainly using [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-785-number-theory-i-fall-2019/lecture-notes/MIT18_785F19_full_notes.pdf) notes on algebraic number theory. Let $L/K$ be a finite degree field extension given by $L=K(\alpha)$ (this is not restrictive by the primitive element theorem). Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Further let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $f=\prod_j g_j^{e_j}$ for irreducible polynomials $g_j$ over $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$.

If $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$, then we can apply the Dedekind-Kummer Theorem that for all primes $\mathfrak{p}\subset K$,

$\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L=\prod_{j} \mathfrak{q_j}^{e_j}$, where $\mathfrak{q_j}=(\mathfrak{p},g_j(\alpha))$.

Further, from remark 6.34, we have that in the case of $K=\mathbb{Q}$, that this theorem holds more broadly (with $p$ a rational prime) for all $(p)\mathcal{O}_L$ as long as $p \nmid [\mathcal{O}_L:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$.

**Question:** What is a nice example of an algebraic number field $L=(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f))/\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathcal{O}_L\neq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, and a prime $(p)\subset \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p | [\mathcal{O}_L:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$ and furthermore such that one CANNOT apply Dedekind-Kummer to factor. More specifically, what does the factorization of $(p)\mathcal{O}_L$ look like?

Comment: Take for instance $f(x)=x^2+3$, $p>2$ any prime.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that p does divide the index. Specifically, I am looking for factorizations of (p) in L where we cannot apply DK

Comment: Then the same polynomial with $p=2$.

Comment: The standard example is to take a cubic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ where $2$ splits completely, eg an irreducible cubic $= x(x-1)(x-2)+2^k f(x)$ with $k$ large enough so that Hensel lemma gives 3 distinct roots in $\Bbb{Q}_2$. There will be 3 distinct  primes above $2$ but only 2 possible values for $n$ in $(2,\alpha-n)$.

Comment: ($f$ is a cubic integer polynomial). Then $x(x-1)(x-2)+2^k f(x)$ will be irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}_3$ whence over $\Bbb{Q}$ if it is $\equiv x^3-3 \bmod 9$.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure I'm entirely following. Could you clarify how you get only 2 possible values for $n$ in $(2,\alpha−n)$. Also, in your second comment why are you bringing up $\mathbb{Q}_3$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}_2$?